# Simulating IBIS Model in modelSim

Tags: simulation, hdl, modelsim

I am developing a logic in an FPGA that will act as a controller for a chip by TI. I got the TI chip IBIS model from the TI website.

My controller is ready and I want to simulate it using ModelSim. But I must have the simulation for  both the controller and the TI chip together.  For this purpose I am trying to use IBIS model of the chip plus my design of the controller in Verilog and simulate in ModelSim. How do I use IBIS model in ModelSim?  Does ModelSim support IBIS? If not then which tool should be used and how do I proceed for this simulation?

Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can use Ibis in Modelsim... For Ibis, you need a signal integrity simulator such as Hyperlynx. But its purpose is to ensure the integrity of high speed signals, including the effects of PCB traces on waveforms.

If you are modelling the digital interactions between your FPGA and the TI chip, you need a "bus functional model" for that chip in your HDL of choice. Contact your TI FAE for this.

If TI can't supply one, you will have to write your own, using the datasheet timing diagrams to model the bus transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am interested in Digital Interaction with my FPGA. If we have the "Bus Functional Model" in HDL (and IBIS model, do I need it for this purpose?) of the chip , then which tool I use for simulation?

Comment: If you have HDL bus functional model, you can use that in Modelsim, then you don't need the Ibis model. (Your PCB signal integrity guy might need it though!)